# Alternative sources of random numbers

Tags: random-number-generator

Considering that algorithmic methods for generating unpredictable streams are hard to come by, I've wondered if any of these potential sources are good for making keys, seeds, and the like:

- stocks, bonds, and other economic indicators.
- weather patterns, temperatures, humidity, stream video of the sky, and other environmental variables.
- photos taken by anyone at all.
- noise in a room.
- traffic patterns.
- seismic activity.

Are any of these methods used?

Comment: 1) You need something *secret* to seed a CSPRNG. 2) How would you obtain that data? If you download it, and you even trust the source to keep the data secret, you still need enough random data beforehand to initiate a TLS connection. But if you already have a good random seed, why bother with that stuff?

Comment: [here](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/evtwote10/tech/full_papers/Clark.pdf) is a paper you may find interesting

Answer (score 2):

Potentially almost any data input can be used as seed. But in general you don't want to use information that can be trusted to have high entropy and be secret all the time. This rules out stock exchange and the weather for instance, as the stock exchange may be down, and there is not much entropy in a clear blue skye.

Almost all of the sources you mention rely on outside phenomenons, which means you have to trust the source. Moreover, you'll need a trusted path to your source, and the trusted path likely requires a random number generator. So you would get into a chicken/egg situation.

What is usually done is to rely on a local phenomenon and then use highly unpredictive measurements. Local phenomenons can be kept secret and measuring in the extreme will mean that you aren't dependent on large fluctuations. For instance a HDD can be used to inform the system about I/O times, and measuring in nano-seconds will give enough entropy for a few bits of seed.

Of course, you neverk know what kind of system you are going to find. So fortunately it starts to be commonplace to include a random number generator in CPU's. An RNG in the CPU or - for instance - in a TPM is probably the best RNG you can find.

Comment: Why is our network down? Well, no earthquakes, but maybe if you shout instead of whisper...

Comment: Agreed with this post, do not rely on outside phenomena. www.random.org can provide you randomness (very good for gaming), and still untrusted. Use something local : local internal clock, processor thermal measurement, time between boot and  the first multicast packet received. Don't expect it to be strong randomness at all, and don't expect a portable solution across platforms, processors, network environment ..... Some processor provide a random generator you can use to build your seeds (and only the seeds). Keys and Numbers MUST be built from a seeded standard PRNG.

Answer (score -8):

I personally found there is the only true randomness generated by computers. It' simply data corruption.

Everyone hates data corruption because it means nothing to them, and true randomness means nothing as well. I experienced corrupted photo files whose broken pixels obscured the original image randomly.

I recommend making data corruption by executing several threads without lock. It will be absolutely unpredictable and there is no definite pattern. I personally did it in python

To make my idea clear, here is a thread about how threads without lock can easily make data corruption

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx

In this post, it is clear that many threads share the same resource, and computers can easily make mistakes. This is why developers use locks.

and I highly recommend trying to predict the outcome of this script. It is dependent on OS, so just suppose the default is Windows (because it is so widely used)

https://github.com/Hojung-Jeong/Silver-Bullet-Random-Number-Generator/blob/master/propellant.py

Comment: Several thread without lock is not unpredictable : the thread scheduler, from a crypto point of view, is highly predictable. Then you can't call it data corruption : the programs(s) running on different threads would be deterministic, and the hardware is deterministic too,  nothing is "corrupted". What you call "unpredictable" is just "can't be analysed by a human brain". Only external events (like interactions from network) would make things behaving slightly differently from a computer to the next one. Have a look on the other post regarding the feeling about external events.

Comment: You would have to make sure that an attacker cannot influence the scheduler as well. You might end up with precious little data corruption otherwise.

Comment: I posted another answer explaining my idea

Comment: @OKLetsbegin, Don't post another answer. Clarify your thoughts in the existing answer. (use the 'edit' link) P.S. I edited them in for you this time.

Comment: Sorry on posting another answer rather than editing the existing one.

Comment: Anyway, it is actually quite obvious that computers DO MAKE MISTAKES. In the case of network, sender and receiver check whether the data packet has been changed or not. In the case of files, loads of people lost their family photos even if there wasn't any obvious problem on the system or hardware. Like the world we live in, computers make imprecision, and we just don't want to see it because it's annoying. However, it is also obvious that it can also be used to make true randomness which is useful for cryptographic purposes

Comment: and one more. I didn't use the thread scheduler algorithm to make randomness. My tool makes randomness because several threads are executed nearly at the same time, and they share same memory space. This is why for ordinary multithreading, people use lock() function since it basically allocates right amount of memory for each thread. However, if there is nothing like that, the result is obviously truly random since each thread interferes one another during operations.

Comment: It looks random to your eyes when you look at it. Can you provide a proof that your algorithm will never enter a periodic stable predictable behavior ?

Comment: It's basically 50:50 chance. Whether the next thread overwrites the previous data or not. In other words, whether that thread will successfully interfere the previous one or not. Because they share the same memory space, there is always 50:50 chance.

Comment: This is why these days, developers are advised to use multi-processing rather than multi-threading for multitasking. They are different in a way that multi-processing utilises separate memory space, while multi-threading allows multiple threads to use same resource. The downside is multi-processing is more resource-hungry, while threading is cheap